# How to continuously delete a rectangle from a previously drawn rectangle while drawing the new rectangle in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to code a gui for highlighting areas of a screen (specifically, greying out areas of an image surrounding a clear rectangle).

I have implemented the generation of a fullscreen transparent widget created after a button press. The widget is covered by a translucent grey rectangle. The user can still see the underlying active screen image which allows them to select a starting point for drawing a rectangle.

The mouse move event after a click event triggers the Update() function which allows the drawing of a new red rectangle.

The problem here is the previously drawn overlay rectangle is disappearing.

How do I fix the following code to draw the red rectangle over the translucent overlay and continually cut the area of the new rectangle from the previous overlay while drawing the rectangle?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QDesktopWidget

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Set the window properties
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Widget")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        
        # Create a button
        self.screenshotButton = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.screenshotButton.move(50, 50)

        # Connect the button's clicked signal to the showTransparentWidget slot
        self.screenshotButton.clicked.connect(self.openTransparentWidget)
        
    def openTransparentWidget(self):
        # Close the main widget
        self.close()
        
        # Create and show the transparent widget
        self.transparentWidget = TransparentWidget()
        self.transparentWidget.show()


class TransparentWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Get the screen dimensions
        desktop = QDesktopWidget()
        screenWidth = desktop.screenGeometry().width()
        screenHeight = desktop.screenGeometry().height()
        
        # Set the size of the widget to the screen dimensions
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
        
        # Set the window flags to make the widget borderless and topmost
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        
        # Set the window transparency
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        
                # Initialize the starting and ending positions of the box to -1
        self.startX = -1
        self.startY = -1
        self.endX = -1
        self.endY = -1

        #call the paintEvent to generate an overlay
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    # Store the starting position of the mouse when it is clicked
        # Set the flag to True
        self.mouseClicked = True
        self.startX = event.x()
        self.startY = event.y()
        print(self.startX, self.startY)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.mouseClicked:
            # Store the current position of the mouse as it is being dragged
            self.endX = event.x()
            self.endY = event.y()
            
            # Redraw the widget to update the box
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # Set the flag to False
        self.mouseClicked = False
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # Create a QPainter object and set it up for drawing
        painter = QPainter(self)

        # Draw translucent overlay over the transparent widget
        if self.startX == -1 and self.endX == -1:
            brush = QBrush(QColor(200, 200, 200, 128))
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            painter.drawRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
            # Set the composition mode to clear
            #painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Clear)
        
        # Draw the box if the starting and ending positions are valid
        if self.startX != -1 and self.endX != -1:
            # Calculate the top-left and bottom-right corners of the box
            topLeftX = min(self.startX, self.endX)
            topLeftY = min(self.startY, self.endY)
            bottomRightX = max(self.startX, self.endX)
            bottomRightY = max(self.startY, self.endY)

            # Set the composition mode to source over - these options seem to have no effect
            #painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_SourceOver)
            #painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Clear)
            #painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_DestinationOut)
            pen = QPen(QColor(255 ,0, 0))
            brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            
            # Draw the empty box (eraseRect also not working)
            painter.drawRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, bottomRightX - topLeftX, bottomRightY - topLeftY)


        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWidget = MainWidget()
mainWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Edit: Here's a sample image I found that shows what I am trying to achieve. (It's actually from a snipping tool which is very similar to what I am trying to achieve)
[image: sample image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide some images of the expected behavior? Note that the translucent background part is irrelevant for the question, and also remember that whenever `paintEvent` is called, it normally redraws the *whole* widget, potentially clearing any previously drawn content: a widget surface is not an image, it has no persistent "memory" of what has been drawn before, or, to be precise, it *can*, since it uses buffering, but that buffer is only for performance purposes, not for "overlayed" drawing operations, and it always clears the previous content of the drawn area.

Comment: For instance, if the widget is hidden (`hide()`, `setVisible(False)`, `close()`, otherwise the window is minimized or the user switches virtual desktop), it will *completely* redrawn when it's made visible again, so the previous buffer will not be considered. If you want persistent "objects", you need to store them in some ways: if you want to use QPainter, then use instance attributes for those objects, otherwise use a QPixmap or the Graphics View framework.

Comment: @musicamante I have found and added a sample image that shows what I am trying to achieve as per your comment. I will proceed in trying to recreate the greyed out background minus the dragged rectangle each time the update function is called.

Comment: So you don't want to "delete" the rectangle, you want to *change* its geometry.

Comment: Now that you have explained it, yes, one could say I'm trying to change the geometry of a rectangle. I'm trying to recreate a fullscreen rectangle with a rectangular hole in it. I just modified the code and now it recreates the fullscreen grey rectangle with the hole in it. Once I release the left mouse button it maintains the clear rectangle in the correct position. What amazes me now is if I hover over the 'hole' I can scroll what's behind it. I did not think the rectangle cut a hole in the widget. I'll post the solution but if you have a better one please post it. @musicamante

Comment: Are you saying that windows *beyond* yours can receive mouse events? That shouldn't happen. What if you close the previous windows *after* showing the new one?

Comment: Yes, the window beyond can receive mouse events when the cursor is over the 'hole'.

Comment: Mh, it seems that this only happens on Windows. Did you try to use `setAutoFillBackground(True)`? Also, using an extremely low alpha value (like 1, for 0-255 scale) for the inner rectangle background brush might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `paintEvent` is called the entire widget is redrawn.
To overcome this, when drawing anything new, also re-draw the previous item.

The short solution is to update `paintEvent`to draw the overlay and clear the new rectangle in the same call.

```
    brush = QBrush(QColor(200, 200, 200, 128))
    painter.setBrush(brush)
    painter.drawRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Clear)
```

Thanks to @musicamante for your support via the comments section.

Here is the full code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QDesktopWidget

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Set the window properties
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Widget")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        
        # Create a button
        self.screenshotButton = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.screenshotButton.move(50, 50)

        # Connect the button's clicked signal to the showTransparentWidget slot
        self.screenshotButton.clicked.connect(self.openTransparentWidget)
        
    def openTransparentWidget(self):
        # Close the main widget
        self.close()
        
        # Create and show the transparent widget
        self.transparentWidget = TransparentWidget()
        self.transparentWidget.show()


class TransparentWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Get the screen dimensions
        desktop = QDesktopWidget()
        screenWidth = desktop.screenGeometry().width()
        screenHeight = desktop.screenGeometry().height()
        
        # Set the size of the widget to the screen dimensions
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
        
        # Set the window flags to make the widget borderless and topmost
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        
        # Set the window transparency
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        
                # Initialize the starting and ending positions of the box to -1
        self.startX = -1
        self.startY = -1
        self.endX = -1
        self.endY = -1

        #call the paintEvent to generate an overlay
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    # Store the starting position of the mouse when it is clicked
        # Set the flag to True
        self.mouseClicked = True
        self.startX = event.x()
        self.startY = event.y()
        print(self.startX, self.startY)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.mouseClicked:
            # Store the current position of the mouse as it is being dragged
            self.endX = event.x()
            self.endY = event.y()
            
            # Redraw the widget to update the box
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # Set the flag to False
        self.mouseClicked = False
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # Create a QPainter object and set it up for drawing
        painter = QPainter(self)

        # Draw translucent overlay over the transparent widget
        if self.startX == -1 and self.endX == -1:
            brush = QBrush(QColor(200, 200, 200, 128))
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            painter.drawRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
            # Set the composition mode to clear
            #painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Clear)
        
        # Draw the box if the starting and ending positions are valid
        if self.startX != -1 and self.endX != -1:
            # Calculate the top-left and bottom-right corners of the box
            topLeftX = min(self.startX, self.endX)
            topLeftY = min(self.startY, self.endY)
            bottomRightX = max(self.startX, self.endX)
            bottomRightY = max(self.startY, self.endY)

            brush = QBrush(QColor(200, 200, 200, 128))
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            painter.drawRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

            
            painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Clear)

            pen = QPen(QColor(255 ,0, 0))
            brush = QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            
            # Draw the empty box
            painter.drawRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, bottomRightX - topLeftX, bottomRightY - topLeftY)


        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWidget = MainWidget()
mainWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You don't have to clear anything, as said, by default, Qt always redraws the whole content of the widget, and even using the composition method is useless in this case, because at that point the area on which you're drawing has *already* been cleared in the buffer. Setting the composition mode only makes sense when drawing upon *existing* content such as using QPainter a QPixmap, or drawing over an area that is being painted by the same QPainter instance (so, for widgets, within the *same* paint event).

Comment: setCompositionMode is required. I tested without and it draws a red Rectangle on top of the full screen grey Rectangle. With it it cuts the hole as desired.

Comment: Oh, you use that for clearing the gray area, I see. Well, in reality, you should just set the clip region, then.

Answer (score 0):

UI drawing (at the low level) normally happens using a *frame buffer*, which is eventually cleared in a specific area in which new painting is going to happen.

This means that you cannot rely on contents previously drawn in another paint event: even when requesting to update a specific region of the widget (ie: using [`update(QRect)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update-2)), that region will be cleared from the buffer, and previous contents doesn't exist any more, and the buffer is also cleared anyway whenever the window is hidden and shown again, like after minimizing and restoring it, or after switching virtual desktop.

In your case, it means that the "background" rectangle will only be painted at start up (when the coordinates are -1), not after that.

The solution is to always draw all the contents, and eventually cut out the area using [`setClipRegion()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setClipRegion).

```py
class TransparentWidget(QWidget):
    area = reference = None
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        
        screenArea = QRect()
        for screen in QApplication.screens():
            screenArea |= screen.geometry()
        self.setGeometry(screenArea)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() != Qt.LeftButton:
            return
        pos = event.pos()
        if self.area:
            span = QRect(-5, -5, 10, 10)
            if span.translated(self.area.topLeft()).contains(pos):
                self.reference = self.area.setTopLeft
            elif span.translated(self.area.topRight()).contains(pos):
                self.reference = self.area.setTopRight
            elif span.translated(self.area.bottomRight()).contains(pos):
                self.reference = self.area.setBottomRight
            elif span.translated(self.area.bottomLeft()).contains(pos):
                self.reference = self.area.setBottomLeft
            else:
                self.reference = None
        if not self.reference:
            self.area = QRect(pos, QSize(1, 1))
            self.reference = self.area.setBottomRight
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.reference:
            self.reference(event.pos())
            self.update()
        elif self.area:
            pos = event.pos()
            span = QRect(-5, -5, 10, 10)
            cursor = None
            if span.translated(self.area.topLeft()).contains(pos):
                cursor = Qt.SizeFDiagCursor
            elif span.translated(self.area.topRight()).contains(pos):
                cursor = Qt.SizeBDiagCursor
            elif span.translated(self.area.bottomRight()).contains(pos):
                cursor = Qt.SizeFDiagCursor
            elif span.translated(self.area.bottomLeft()).contains(pos):
                cursor = Qt.SizeBDiagCursor
            if cursor is not None:
                self.setCursor(cursor)
            else:
                self.unsetCursor()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.reference = None
        if self.area is not None:
            self.area = self.area.normalized()
        self.update()
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        if self.area is not None:
            r = QRegion(self.rect())
            r ^= QRegion(self.area.normalized().adjusted(1, 1, 0, 0))
            painter.setClipRegion(r)

        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(200, 200, 200, 128))

        if self.area is not None:
            painter.setPen(QColor(255 ,0, 0))
            painter.drawRect(self.area.normalized())
```

Notes:

- QDesktopWidget is obsolete in Qt5, use [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) instead;
- you should always consider the case of multiple screen computers; if you *specifically* do *not* want to show your widget in all screens, then just use `showFullScreen();
- whenever possible and it makes sense, use Qt objects functions, which are normally quite fast and provide better readability (for instance, using QPoint, QRect and functions like [`QRect.normalized()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#normalized));
- calling `self.update()` in the `__init__` is pointless: `update()` doesn't immediately redraw the widget, it only *schedules* an update, and since the first painting will happen anyway as soon as the widget is shown, there's no point in doing it;